# VBA Greater Than Function Not Working

Tags: string, vba, if-statement, numeric

I have an issue where I am trying to compare a values that can be alphanumeric, only numeric, or only alphabetic.

The code originally worked fine for comparing anything within the same 100s group (IE 1-99 with alphabetic components). However when I included 100+ into it, it malfunctioned.

The current part of the code reads:

```
            For j = 1 To thislength
                If lennew < j Then
                    enteredval = Left("100A", lennew)
                ElseIf lennew >= j Then
                    enteredval = Left("100A", j)
                End If
                If lenold < j Then
                    cellval = Left("67", lenold)
                ElseIf lenold >= j Then
                    cellval = Left("67", j)
                End If 
                'issue occurs here
                If enteredval >= cellval Then
                    newrow = newrow+1
                End If
            Next j
```

The issue occurs in the last `if` statement. 
When cycling through the 100 is greater than the 67 but still skips over. I tried to declare them both as strings (above this part of code) to see if that would help but it didn't.

What I am trying to accomplish is to sort through a bunch of rows and find where it should go. IE the 100A should go between 100 and 100B.

Sorry `lennew=len("100A")` and `lennold=len("67")`. And `thislength=4`or whatever is larger of the two lengths.

Comment: You're wanting to sort the numeric portion numerically, but if those are equal, sort the balance alphabetically, correct?

Comment: Yes. Unless there is a better way to do it. I basically just want it to show up as. 69,69A,69B,70A,99A,100,100A. ( or any variation of numbers and letters). The issue i was having is that 69 appears larger than 100 for the first little bit but somehow the code won't recognize it now that it is indeed larger.

Comment: You'll need to cast the numeric portion to numeric types before you use equity comparisons on them.  See [Comparison Operators](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5813/operators/20479/comparison-operators#t=201702151525369696781) in documentation.

Comment: If the values are strings, you can do a Val() on them, and that will compare leading numeric portions only, eg "1000A" and "1000B" with both return 1000. The problem is you're code is targeting very specific string prefixes and in order to really solve the problem you're going to have to solve the comparison more generically...

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for the help. I have a few ideas I will test out and get back to you on if they work. Namely I will check the values. If the values are equal. Only then will i go through the sorting process to see which value is greater.

Comment: @TimSwingle I've posted some code to give you an idea of where I'm heading. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have 'lennew = Right("Str100A", Len(Val("Str100A")) + 1)' and am getting an error on the Val() function saying "Variable required-can-t assign to this expression." Any thoughts?

Comment: I changed the created a variable to store the val() and used that inside the len(). Which allowed it to compile.

Comment: @DavidW , Good morning. I have a slightly new issue I was wondering if you could help me with. I have a mid function used to find the value between 2 sections. `ltrOAS = Mid(CStr(70A.01a-01)), 7, 8 - 1)`. Now this should return "a" but it's returning "a-01". Thoughts?

Comment: Hi @TimSwingle - I think your third parameter (8-1) is telling the Mid function to return 7 characters at the starting position  defined by the 2nd parameter - 7. Since the string isn't long enough to provide that many characters starting at that position, it merely returns the rest of the string. Now, this may be left-field, but I infer you mean the argument to CSTr to be the *quoted* string "70A.01a-01", correct?

Comment: @DavidW Yea the CStr was taken above earlier, I just can't use some of my variables so I replaced that on this with copy/pasting from VBA. I have the same code written above in my code for the comparison that works like a charm, but for some reason it will not work for this part. I thought that the 7 to 7 character issue might be causing the problem as well, so I just did `ltrOAS = Mid(CStr("70A.01a-01"), 7)` and it still returned "a-01" instead of "a".

Comment: @TimSwingle Without a length specification, I believe Mid will return the rest of the string at the specified character position. If you just need the one character, supply 1 as the third parameter - but can you rely on that generically? I mean, these kinds of specific situations can get a little hairy to maintain...

Comment: @DavidW OH! I see where I went wrong though. I was assuming that the mid function was basing itself on the number of characters in the string and not the number of characters I wanted returned. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TimSwingle You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to solve the comparison problem by attacking specific values, and that's going to be a problem to maintain. I'd make the problem more generic by creating a function that supplies takes two values returns -1 if the first operand is "before" the second, 0 if they are the same, and 1 if the first operand is "after" the second per your rules.

You could then restructure your code to eliminate the specific hardcoded prefix testing and then just call the comparison function directly, eg (and this is COMPLETELY untested, off-the-cuff, and my VBA is VERRRRRY stale :) but the idea is there: (it also assumes the existence of a simple string function called StripPrefix that just takes a string and strips off any leading digits, which I suspect you can spin up fairly readily yourself)

```
Function CompareCell(Cell1 as String, Cell2 as String) as Integer

    Dim result as integer
    Dim suffix1 as string
    Dim suffix2 as string 

    if val(cell1)< val(cell2) Then
       result = -1
    else if val(cell1)>val(cell2) then
       result = 1
    else if val(cell1)=val(cell2) then
       if len(cell1)=len(cell2) then
          result =0
       else
         ' write code to strip leading numeric prefixes
         ' You must supply StripPrefix, but it's pretty simple
         ' I just omitted it here for clarity
         suffix1=StripPrefix(cell1) ' eg returns "ABC" for "1000ABC"
         suffix2=StripPrefix(cell2)
         if suffix1 < suffix2 then
            result = -1
         else if suffix1 > suffix2 then
            result = 1
         else
            result = 0
         end if
   end if

   return result

end function
```

A function like this then allows you to take *any* two cell references and compare them directly to make whatever decision you need:

```
if CompareCell(enteredval,newval)>=0 then
   newrow=newrow+1
end if
```